# TFS Build definition - how to specify condition for scheduled build

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

I want to reorganize our build system.
Some of the builds are depended on some other builds and I want to make sure that they are not queued automatically if condition is not met(build that they depend on is not finished without errors).
Does anybody know how to do this?

We are using TFS 2012.

Comment: Have you seen these? 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dstfs/archive/2012/10/12/using-tfs-2012-team-build-to-control-build-order-of-multiple-solutions.aspx

http://blog.stangroome.com/2011/09/06/queue-another-team-build-when-one-team-build-succeeds/

Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: second link can maybe work, I need to try it, but I was hoping I can set it up externally without changing build definitions...thanks anyway